# C++: How to get two separate number inputs from text file, with dependency

Tags: c++

I have to program this in C++

> *You're given a sequence on N whole numbers. Can you find the bigger one?*

The problem is this:
the input for the program consists of a txt file ( called input.txt ) with the quantity of numbers in the first line and the actual sequence in the second. 

For example:

```
7
13 87 -4 354 3767 567 123
```

The indications require to get the first line, then get the second one with the program getting the number indicated in the first ( and possibly verifying if there is the amount of numbers required in the first ), then get the bigger number out of the sequence and print it in a fil called output.txt




I already searched and tried with some `fstream` methods but I cant't figure out how to get to the result.

 Thanks in advance

Comment: `I already searched and tried with some fstream methods but I cant't figure out how to get to the result` Do you have a code?

Comment: We won't write your program for you. StackOverflow is full of questions about reading integers from text files.